# Server 2016 bluescreen vmswitch.sys

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2016, bsod

I am facing a serious issue on two Hyper-V-hosts with Windows Server 2016 Datacenter.

Without external influence they crash and all guest VMs too. The STOP code is UNEXPECTED_KERNEL_MODE_TRAP 0x0000007f and it is caused by vmswitch.sys
A simple reboot does not fix this, it always crashes 8 to 10 times in a row until it works properly again.

This problem occurs on two of our servers with completely different hardware.
I tried several versions of the nic driver, but it did not resolve the issue. VMQ is already disabled on the nics and in the VM settings.

I updated all drivers und bios to the latest versions. In one server I changed the Ethernet adapter card, but the issue persisted.

Here you can download a recent minidump file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76615769/110416-20546-01.dmp

I analyzed a recent memory.dmp with WinDbg and the failure was caused by vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet.

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

UNEXPECTED_KERNEL_MODE_TRAP (7f)
This means a trap occurred in kernel mode, and it's a trap of a kind
that the kernel isn't allowed to have/catch (bound trap) or that
is always instant death (double fault).  The first number in the
bugcheck params is the number of the trap (8 = double fault, etc)
Consult an Intel x86 family manual to learn more about what these
traps are. Here is a *portion* of those codes:
If kv shows a taskGate
        use .tss on the part before the colon, then kv.
Else if kv shows a trapframe
        use .trap on that value
Else
        .trap on the appropriate frame will show where the trap was taken
        (on x86, this will be the ebp that goes with the procedure KiTrap)
Endif
kb will then show the corrected stack.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000008, EXCEPTION_DOUBLE_FAULT
Arg2: fffff80234218e70
Arg3: fffff80234202fc0
Arg4: fffff80d94e0fa0a

Debugging Details:
------------------


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 402

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  14393.447.amd64fre.rs1_release_inmarket.161102-0100

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  LENOVO

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  Lenovo ThinkServer TS430

SYSTEM_SKU:  OEM_String

SYSTEM_VERSION:  04411GG

BIOS_VENDOR:  LENOVO

BIOS_VERSION:  4.25

BIOS_DATE:  08/08/2016

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  LENOVO

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  GA-6UASV2

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  N/A

DUMP_TYPE:  0

BUGCHECK_P1: 8

BUGCHECK_P2: fffff80234218e70

BUGCHECK_P3: fffff80234202fc0

BUGCHECK_P4: fffff80d94e0fa0a

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x7f_8

TRAP_FRAME:  fffff80234218e70 -- (.trap 0xfffff80234218e70)
NOTE: The trap frame does not contain all registers.
Some register values may be zeroed or incorrect.
rax=ffff622415d5af2e rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=ffffd982943bfd10
rdx=0000000000000065 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff80d94e0fa0a rsp=fffff80234202fc0 rbp=0000000000000000
 r8=0000000000000366  r9=fffff80234206cb0 r10=0000000000000000
r11=fffff80d94e57f83 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x1a:
fffff80d`94e0fa0a 4c89442438      mov     qword ptr [rsp+38h],r8 ss:0018:fffff802`34202ff8=????????????????
Resetting default scope

CPU_COUNT: 8

CPU_MHZ: d40

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 3a

CPU_STEPPING: 9

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,3a,9,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 1B'00000000 (cache) 1B'00000000 (init)

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  FELIX-WIN10

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  12-03-2016 16:29:37.0725

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.14321.1024 amd64fre

STACK_OVERFLOW: Stack Limit: fffff80234203000. Use (kF) and (!stackusage) to investigate stack usage.

STACKUSAGE_FUNCTION: The function at address 0xFFFFF80D94E7411C was blamed for the stack overflow. It is using 15264 bytes of stack total in 106 instances (likely recursion).

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+6472c
fffff80d`94e7411c 90              nop

STACK_COMMAND:  .trap 0xfffff80234218e70 ; kb

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  71a30400073d671566ecf9d703e6e5093d8f333d

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  b894bbd73b89626ade2941eb152107226b6892b2

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  6c44de534055635e7718f6cd495814d6f86d55df

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  ba45e990

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  1

SYMBOL_NAME:  vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+6472c

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: vmswitch

IMAGE_NAME:  vmswitch.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  5819bf9a

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  6472c

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x7f_8_STACK_USAGE_RECURSION_vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet

BUCKET_ID:  0x7f_8_STACK_USAGE_RECURSION_vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x7f_8_STACK_USAGE_RECURSION_vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet

TARGET_TIME:  2016-12-03T14:54:56.000Z

OSBUILD:  14393

OSSERVICEPACK:  0

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  400

PRODUCT_TYPE:  3

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 Server TerminalServer DataCenter SingleUserTS

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2016-11-02 11:17:03

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  161102-0100

BUILDLAB_STR:  rs1_release_inmarket

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.14393.447.amd64fre.rs1_release_inmarket.161102-0100

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME: 5c3

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x7f_8_stack_usage_recursion_vmswitch!vmspktparseipv4packet

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {54616c76-71d3-7277-08ba-c2d2fa4a114c}
```

Here is the call stack:

```
nt!KeBugCheckEx
nt!KiBugCheckDispatch+0x69
nt!KiDoubleFaultAbort+0xb3
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x1a
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParseIPv4Packet+0x6472c
vmswitch!VmsPktParsePacket+0x156
vmswitch!VmsNblGenerateRssHash+0xd3
vmswitch!VmsVmNicPvtPacketForward+0x234
vmswitch!VmsRouterDeliverNetBufferLists+0x81a
vmswitch!VmsExtPtReceiveNetBufferLists+0x193
NDIS!ndisMIndicateNetBufferListsToOpen+0x11e
NDIS!ndisMTopReceiveNetBufferLists+0x265fc
NDIS!ndisCallReceiveHandler+0x47
NDIS!NdisMIndicateReceiveNetBufferLists+0x735
vmswitch!VmsExtMpIndicatePackets+0x7b4
vmswitch!VmsExtMpSendNetBufferLists+0x5a8
NDIS!ndisMSendNBLToMiniportInternal+0xee
NDIS!NdisSendNetBufferLists+0x36c
vmswitch!VmsExtPtRouteNetBufferLists+0x3fe
vmswitch!VmsPtNicReceiveNetBufferLists+0x8a0
NDIS!ndisMIndicateNetBufferListsToOpen+0x11e
NDIS!NdisMIndicateReceiveNetBufferLists+0x26ca3
e1r65x64!DriverEntry+0x12c1b
e1r65x64!DriverEntry+0x13eaf
e1r65x64!DriverEntry+0x1accd
e1r65x64!DriverEntry+0x1afdb
e1r65x64!DriverEntry+0x1a76c
NDIS!ndisInterruptDpc+0x1c9
nt!KiExecuteAllDpcs+0x2b1
nt!KiRetireDpcList+0x5df
nt!KiIdleLoop+0x5a
```

Another interesting point is, one server ran fine with only 2008 R2 guests. After adding a Server 2016 guest, the bluescreen started on this server, too. The event log of neither the host nor the guest contains any helpful information.

I already discussed this problem in the TechNet forum, but the tips there did not help. Maybe someone here can help me

Thanks for your efforts,
FelR